# Trying to retrieve colour from touch point on UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I've tried this code, but it comes up with wrong numbers.  Sometimes it will click transparent parts and come back with values, and sometimes it will click coloured parts with no values.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    UIColor *color = [self colorAtPosition: location];

    const CGFloat* components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    NSLog(@"Red: %f", components[0]);
    NSLog(@"Green: %f", components[1]);
    NSLog(@"Blue: %f", components[2]);
    NSLog(@"Alpha: %f", CGColorGetAlpha(color.CGColor));
    NSLog(@"x:%f y:%f",location.x,location.y);
}

- (UIColor *)colorAtPosition:(CGPoint)position {

    CGRect sourceRect = CGRectMake(position.x, position.y, 1.f, 1.f);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.image.CGImage, sourceRect);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *buffer = malloc(4);
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(buffer, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, bitmapInfo);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 1.f, 1.f), imageRef);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CGFloat r = buffer[0] / 255.f;
    CGFloat g = buffer[1] / 255.f;
    CGFloat b = buffer[2] / 255.f;
    CGFloat a = buffer[3] / 255.f;

    free(buffer);

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a];
}
```

Comment: http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used your code and it works with some changes :D!
(But I'm using a long Press Gesture instead)

```
- (void)didRecognizeLogPressGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{    
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:self.imageView];
        point.x = point.x*self.imageView.image.size.width/self.imageView.bounds.size.width;
        point.y = point.y*self.imageView.image.size.height/self.imageView.bounds.size.height;


        CGRect sourceRect   = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, 1.f, 1.f);
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.imageView.image.CGImage, sourceRect);

        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        unsigned char *buffer = malloc(4);
        CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big;
        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(buffer, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, bitmapInfo);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1), imageRef);

        CGFloat r = buffer[0] / 255.f;
        CGFloat g = buffer[1] / 255.f;
        CGFloat b = buffer[2] / 255.f;
        CGFloat a = buffer[3] / 255.f;

        free(buffer);

        self.viewColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a];
    }
}
```

The main change is:

```
    point.x = point.x*self.imageView.image.size.width/self.imageView.bounds.size.width;
    point.y = point.y*self.imageView.image.size.height/self.imageView.bounds.size.height;
```

With that, you are converting the coordinates relative to the real image size.